# Why does the cookie property of my Httpwebresponse object remain null ?(WP8)

Tags: cookies, windows-phone-8, httpwebresponse

Im requesting on a web server with Basic Authent and the server is supposed to return a cookie.It does when i use a web brower i can check it in FiddlerProxy... When i debug my code the response.cookie remains null. Here is my code.Thanks for your help

```
  public void ConnexionNT(string password,string user)

    {
        CookieContainer _cookiecontainer=new CookieContainer();
        try
        {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL_CONNEXION);

            request.Method = "GET";

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);

            request.CookieContainer = _cookiecontainer;

            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponse), request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
    private void GetResponse(IAsyncResult MyresponseAsync)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)MyresponseAsync.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(MyresponseAsync);


        if (response.Cookies!=null) //REMAINS NULL
        {    //SAVE COOKIE}
     }
```

**EDIT**

If i move the Cookiecontainer decalrtion at the class level the cookie property of httpwebresponse is not null anymore...

**EDIT2**

Is this code correct to receive cookie from the server ?

```
 public void ConnexionNT(string password,string user)

    {

        try
        {

            HttpWebRequest request=     (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL_CONNEXION);

            request.Method = "GET";

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);

            request.CookieContainer = _cookiecontainer;

            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponse),request);


        }

        catch(HttpRequestException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Un problème de connexion avec  le serveur a eu lieu.", "Echec Authentification", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Une erreur a eu lieu","Echec Authentification", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

    }



    private void GetResponse(IAsyncResult MyresponseAsync)
    {

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)MyresponseAsync.AsyncState;

            if (request != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(MyresponseAsync);


 //Not null but EMPTY WHY?        if (response.Cookies != null)
                    {
                        using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                        {
                            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("CookiesFile", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            {
                                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(isfs))
                                {
                                    foreach (Cookie cookieValue in response.Cookies)
                                    {
                                        sw.WriteLine("Cookie: " + cookieValue.ToString());

                                    }
                                    sw.Close();
                                }

                            }
                            //declenche l'event pour lancer la navigation sur la vue "codepin"
                            if (event_GetCookie != null && response.Cookies.Count>0)
                                event_GetCookie.Invoke();

                        }

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN:

> If the CookieContainer property of the associated HttpWebRequest is null, the Cookies property will also be null. Any cookie information sent by the server will be available in the Headers property, however.

you need to create a `CookieContainer` in the request.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(args[0]);
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();



        // Print the properties of each cookie. 
        foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cookie:");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", cook.Name, cook.Value);
        }
```

Comment: I dont get it...I set a cookie container in the httpwebrequest... CookieContainer _cookiecontainer=new CookieContainer();request.CookieContainer = _cookiecontainer;..am i missing something ?

Comment: Can you try to move your CookieContainer declaration to class level?

Comment: Ok now the cookie property is not null but remains empty...and i can't check the exchanges between client and server by using windows phone emulator (FiddlerProxy not working) thanks for ur help

Comment: You can use fiddler with the emulator or the device. http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorWindowsPhone7

Comment: I can't make it works...i tried also with charles, wireshark and Microsof network monitoring...But eachtime im not able to see what going on between my WP emulator and the server...Ca you tell me if my code is correct i wrote it in EDIT2 thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this. may this will helps you

```
 public void ConnexionNT(string password,string user)    
        {
            CookieContainer _cookiecontainer=new CookieContainer();
            try
            {   
                CookieContainer container = new CookieContainer();
                container.Add(new Uri("http://yoursite"), new Cookie("name", "value"));
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://yoursite");
                request.CookieContainer = container;
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain);
                request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponse), request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        private void GetResponse(IAsyncResult MyresponseAsync)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)MyresponseAsync.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(MyresponseAsync);    

            if (response.Cookies!=null) //REMAINS NULL
            {    //SAVE COOKIE}
         }
```

Comment: thanks but i get same results with your solution and andras's one which i found a little more simple...