# Can't get cookie with HttpClient and windows phone 8

Tags: c#, cookies, windows-phone-8, forms-authentication

I have to do forms authentication to use a service, but I can't get cookie. One solution is every time did two requests one to login page and one to resource I want to get. I did the same thing on wpf and console apps and it works well but not in windows phone 8. here is my code.

```
CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "someusername"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "somepassword")
            });
            var response = await client.PostAsync("mysite.com/login", content);
            string res = await client.GetStringAsync("mysite.com/posts/getposts");

            Uri uri = new Uri("mysite.com/");

            var responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri);
            foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
            {
                string name = cookie.Name;
                string value = cookie.Value;
            }
```

Comment: how much cookies does the `CookieContainer` contain, using `.Count`?

Comment: 1 - WPF and Console apps, 0 - windows phone 8 app :D

Answer (score 1):

Check that the cookie you are trying to read is not an HttpOnly cookie, in which case will not be exposed in the CookieContainer. If that's the situation, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21737087/262036) should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656174/why-does-the-cookie-property-of-my-httpwebresponse-object-remain-null-wp8) will help you. Check your `repsone`'s `Cookies` property, whether it contains the cookies.